# Twilio: How to dial multiple phone numbers, each with IVR (say + gather for each)?

Tags: twilio, phone-call, ivr, twilio-twiml, conference

From my app, I need to dial in 2 users with say = "hello < name1 > this is FantasticApp. Press 1 to be connected to your buddy < name2 >".

Only after both users answered and pressed 1, they are connected in a call.
If user1 answered and accepted first and while waiting for user2, I want to play music to user1.

How can I write this Twiml?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this using the `<Conference>` part of TwiML. Here's an example using Ruby/Sinatra.

First you build your initial response when the user dials the number:

```
post '/call' do
  "<Response>
     <Gather action='/next' numDigits='1'>
       <Say>Hello! This is FantasticApp, press 1 to be connected with your buddy</Say>
     </Gather>
   </Response>"
end
```

Then the `/next` endpoint will put the caller into a conference to wait for their buddy.

```
post '/next' do
  "<Response>
     <Dial>
       <Conference waitUrl='/your-awesome-hold-music.mp3'>FantasticApp conference</Conference>
     </Dial>
   </Response>"
end
```

I hope that helps, let me know if you have any other questions.